# FAX PDF using windows fax server 2008

Tags: windows, fax

We have windows server 2008. Whenever we try to fax a PDF document using windows fax and scan console, adobe reader instance is getting opened automatically. How to avoid this?

In another forum the following details have been given. I don't understand that. Can anyone please help me?

acrobat 5 and above doesn't automatically terminate after print, hence it does not response with an exit code for the server to terminate.

How we have done it is setup a web service on the server with the fax card / fax console, installed Acrobat Reader 4, created a file assoication to .pdf4 extension (which we generate out of our app), ie. Under the "File Type" for PDF4, we have created a "printto" action, and the program is  `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 4.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe /t %1 %2 %3 %4`

Use DDE, Application = AcroRd32 and Topic = System

From what I understand, the /t option asks it to terminate after print; when you submit a job to the Fax Console, it opens out the assoicated viewer and issue a "printto" command so that it emulates what you are doing if you had print the document to that printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the PDF to a tiff image first. My guess is that is why the adobe reader is being opened.